# Function not executing onsubmit

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with my HTML?

```
<form onsubmit='createComment(commentType, currentQuestionID.toString(),
    $("#addCommentAuthor").val(),
    $("#addCommentEmail").val(),
    $("#addCommentContent").val(),
    $("#addCommentDate").val());' method='POST'>
```

`createComment` is supposed to log 'asd' to the console but it doesn't seem to execute on form submit.

Also, I have another function, which works, and prevents page refresh by returning false. However, if I add return false to the above function, the form simply doesn't get sent. Why is that? They seem identical, and should behave in the same way?

```
<form onsubmit='createQuestion(quizType, $("#submitQ").val(),
    $("#submitA1").val(), $("#submitA2").val(),
    $("#submitA3").val(), $("#submitA4").val(),
    $("#submitCorrect").val(), $("#submitExpl").val(),
    $("#submitAuthor").val(), $("#submitDesc").val(),
    $("#submitDate").val());return false;' method='POST'>
```

Comment: return false; would prevent form submit

Answer (score 0):

Please change currentQuestionID.toString() to currentQuestionID and check.

```
regards,
```